# What to do when a tag is misspelled?

Tags: discussion, tags

A tag named `andorid` is added recently. I searched on google and found nothing about it.

I thought, it is nothing but misspelling of `android`.

I went to see the tagged question and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405897/nestedscrollview-is-not-scrolling-due-to-editext) question. Having a look on it, I became sure that it is just by mistake and I edited the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31405897/revisions) tag.

So now, my question is what to do to remove such misspelled tag?

Comment: Though my question is marked as duplicate, but I think new comers would search most on my tittle as they could not tag new name.

Comment: ...at which point they will click on the link to the other question and get their answer. That's what marking as a duplicate is for.

Comment: Obviously, You exactly described my intention. @MikeMcCaughan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit questions with the misspelled tag to use the correct tag and then an automated process will remove the misspelled tag when it runs